# Palindrome php some cases are right some are wrong

Tags: php

Can someone please check my code because in this code on some cases the output is correct but when I try to test this input zzzazzazz the output is not what I expect.

```
function checkPalindrome($inputString) {
$arr1 = str_split($inputString);
$arrlength = count($arr1);
$max = $arrlength-1;

   for($min = 0; $min<$max; $min++){
     if($arr1[$min] == $arr1[$max]){        
        $max--;
        return true;     
     }
     return false;  
   }     
}
checkPalindrome("zzzazzazz");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is all over the place.  There are many ways to solve this problem, and I don't think you even need to split the string into an array of characters.  But, assuming you want to do it that way, here is a working implementation:

```
$inputString = "HELLOOLLEH";
$arr1 = str_split($inputString);
$arrlength = count($arr1);
$isPalindrome = true;

for ($i = 0; $i < $arrlength / 2; ++$i) {
    if ($arr1[$i] != $arr1[$arrlength-$i-1]) {
        $isPalindrome = false;
        break;
    }
}

echo $isPalindrome;
```

### Demo

The basic idea is to walk down the string, starting at both ends, and compare characters on both sides, one by one.  If we find a case where the two characters are not the same, then the string cannot be a palindrome.  Note that this approach covers both even and odd length palindromes.  In the case of an odd length palindrome, the center character can be anything, and the loop I wrote won't even examine it.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning true if only the first char matches the last char - you are not checking for the rest

```
   if($arr1[$min] == $arr1[$max]){     
        $max--;
        return true;     
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler way using [strrev()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php) and removing all but a-z chars then lowercasing.

```
<?php
function checkPalindrome($str) {
    $str = strtolower(preg_replace('/[^a-z]+/i', '', $str));
    return $str == strrev($str);
}

// test, few taken from http://www.palindromelist.net
$palindromes = [
    'A but tuba.',    
    'madam',    
    'hannah',    
    'A dog, a plan, a canal: pagoda.',    
    'Nurses run',    
    'A dog! A panic in a pagoda!',    
    'A lad named E. Mandala',    
    'A man, a plan, a canal: Panama.',    
    'A man, a plan, a cat, a ham, a yak, a yam, a hat, a canal-Panama!',    
    'A new order began, a more Roman age bred Rowena.',    
    'Decaf and DNA faced.',    
    'Dennis and Edna sinned.',    
    'Devil never even lived.',    
    'Dr. Awkward',    
    'On a clover, if alive, erupts a vast, pure evil; a fire volcano.',    
    'See, slave, I demonstrate yet arts no medieval sees.',    
    'Star? Come, Donna Melba, I’m an amiable man – no Democrats!',    
    'Swap God for a janitor; rot in a jar of dog paws.',    
];

foreach ($palindromes as $str) {
    echo $str.(checkPalindrome($str) ? ' is' : 'is not').' a palindrome'.PHP_EOL;
}
```

https://3v4l.org/tuHnU

**Result:**

```
A but tuba. is a palindrome
madam is a palindrome
hannah is a palindrome
A dog, a plan, a canal: pagoda. is a palindrome
Nurses run is a palindrome
A dog! A panic in a pagoda! is a palindrome
A lad named E. Mandala is a palindrome
A man, a plan, a canal: Panama. is a palindrome
A man, a plan, a cat, a ham, a yak, a yam, a hat, a canal-Panama! is a palindrome
A new order began, a more Roman age bred Rowena. is a palindrome
Decaf and DNA faced. is a palindrome
Dennis and Edna sinned. is a palindrome
Devil never even lived. is a palindrome
Dr. Awkward is a palindrome
On a clover, if alive, erupts a vast, pure evil; a fire volcano. is a palindrome
See, slave, I demonstrate yet arts no medieval sees. is a palindrome
Star? Come, Donna Melba, I’m an amiable man – no Democrats! is a palindrome
Swap God for a janitor; rot in a jar of dog paws. is a palindrome
```

Answer (score 0):

You can supply  the string to check as a parameter to this function:

```
function checkPalindrome($text) {
    //Eliminate punctuation and spaces
    $str = preg_replace('/[^a-z]+/i', '', $text);
    
    // Force lower case
    $str = strtolower($str);
    
    //compare
    $verdict = $str == strrev($str) ? '"' . $text . '" ' . 'is a palindrome' : '"' . $text . '"' . ' is not a palindrome';
    
    return $verdict;
}

echo checkPalindrome("Red rum, sir, is murder");
```

See demo **[here](https://rextester.com/LABYC97151)**.